# Is WebMehods a BPMN 2.0 supporting Process Engine?

Tags: jbpm, webmethods, business-process-management, bpmn, activiti

As the title says everything, If the answer is yes then I would like to have a nice tutorial/link for using WebMethods as a BPMN 2.0 process engine.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes with the 8.2 version : http://documentation.softwareag.com/webmethods/wmsuites/wmsuite8-2_ga/readme/ProcessEngine_8-2-SP1_readme.pdf

> Process Engine now supports BPMN 2.0 semantics corresponding to the BPMN 2.0 constructs that 
>   webMethods Process Development supports in notation.

If you want a good tuto, you could appreciate this one : http://techcommunity.softwareag.com/ecosystem/communities/public/Developer/webmethods/products/bpm_suite/tutorials/Subprocess/subprocesses_index.html